# Find the first non-consecutive number in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The challenge is to find the first non-consecutive number in python. I have managed to do it with a library called more_itertools, but the challenge requires that no library be involved. How can I solve it?
This is my code:

```
from more_itertools import consecutive_groups

def first_non_consecutive(l):
    g = []
    for grp in consecutive_groups(l):
        g.append(list(grp))
    if len(g) > 1:
        return g[1][0]
```

Comment: `for n in range(len(lst)-1): if lst[n+1] - lst[n] != 1: return lst[n+1]`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with `start` parameter to your advantage here.

```
def first_non_consecutive(lst):
    for i, j in enumerate(lst, lst[0]):
        if i!=j:
            return j

first_consecutive([1,2,3,4,6,7,8])
# 6
```

Comment: I know this is old, but you can also do this
```
def nonconsecutive(arr: list) -> list:
    return [i for i, j in zip(arr, arr[1:]) if i+1 != j]
```
and then return the first value if you want all of them...